# Xcode OpenGL ES: Framebuffer is not complete

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures, framebuffer

I am trying to render an image to a texture in OpenGL ES to implement off-screen Sobel filter. Following this link http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html, I create a resulting texture named **sobelTexture** and a render frame buffer named **depthBuffer**, then respectively attach them to GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 and GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT of a newly created frame buffer. The code is shown in bellow.

```
    // Create a texture associated with the frame buffer to render image into
    GLuint sobelTexture;
    glGenTextures(1, &sobelTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, sobelTexture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    GLuint depthBuffer;
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depthBuffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16, width, height);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);


    // Create frame buffer
    GLuint frameBuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, sobelTexture, 0);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depthBuffer);
```

However, when I check the frame buffer status using the bellow code, it returns what is different from GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE.

```
    if (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    {
        NSLog(@"! ERROR: frame buffer is not completed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Moreover, If I change the data type GL_FLOAT in glTexImage2D() function to GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, the frame buffer will be marked as complete. But I cannot use it because, in my fragment shader, the output color components are of float type.

How could I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: The first guess would be that non-POT textures are not supported. That would mean your width and height must be POT (power of two) so try to input some POT values for width and height such as 1024.